# Freemarker not supporting next line i.e., \n

Tags: freemarker

I am using the Freemarker template to generate PDF in the spring boot application.

I have a string that has `\n`

> Example: "This \n is \n a \n new \n line"

But after generating the PDF it's coming as

**Actual Output:**

```
This is a new line
```

**Expected Output:**

```
This 
is 
a 
new 
line
```

I tried to replace it as suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51631777/2462531)

```
myString.replace("\n", "\${'" + '\n' + "'}") // ${'\n'}
```

but the result is:

```
This ${' '} is ${' '} a ${' '} new ${' '} line
```

This is the configuration:

```
@Bean("freemarkerConfig")
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun getFreemarkerConfiguration(): freemarker.template.Configuration {
        val config = freemarker.template.Configuration(freemarker.template.Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23)
        config.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(File(imagesFolder!!))
        config.defaultEncoding = "UTF-8"
        config.outputFormat = HTMLOutputFormat.INSTANCE
        val ctl = ClassTemplateLoader(javaClass, "/templates")
        config.objectWrapper = DefaultObjectWrapper()
        val ftl = FileTemplateLoader(File(templatesFolder!!))
        val mtl = MultiTemplateLoader(arrayOf(ctl, ftl))
        config.templateLoader = mtl
        return config
    }
```

How to get the text in the next line when there is `\n` using Freemarker?

Comment: So the question is, what generates PDF from the template output, and how? What format does that PDF generator expect as its input (where it's input is the output of the template)?

Comment: If the `\n` are coming from the data-model (and I assume they are real line breaks, and you just refer to them with the Java string literal syntax), then when you print them with `${...}`, they will be also there in the output. The problem will be with what generates PDF from that output, but see my previous question.

Comment: @ddekany I am using `itextpdf` to convert HTML to PDF
`val writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, FileOutputStream(fpdFile))`

Comment: So the template outputs HTML. Then outputting `<br>` should produce a line break in the PDF. Can you try again with that? Like, just enter `line1<br>line2` directly into the template.

Comment: Tried already with <br> and also with <br/> but same result

Comment: Tried these `myString.replace("\n", "\${" + '\n' + "}")` and `myString.replace("\n", "<br>")` and `myString.replace("\n", "<br/>")`

Comment: Well, I don't see much of the code, I'm not sure what gets into the template. That's why I said to put the `<br>` directly into the template, just to see that the PDF writer converts it properly, with a minimum chance of other interfering mistakes.

Comment: Yeah in the HTML template if I keep `<br>` it is converting to PDF fine and I see there is a line break in PDF and HTML preview. But when I pass the same data from the model to that HTML template it is not rendering in PDF.

Comment: So then the template doesn't get the value after the replacement. And only replacing with `<br/>` is meaningful, the other with `\${` etc. is not. But you can also do the replacement in the template, like instead of `${s}`, you can write `${s?replace('\n', '<br>')}`.

Comment: Yeah, I will try that, and is this works? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16108402/2462531

Comment: Tried this directly in my HTML template but still same result
`<td >${myString?replace('\n', '<br>')}</td>`
Where myString is "This \n is \n a \n new \n line"

Comment: Does that string contain `\n` literally, or it contains real new line characters? If it's literally `\n`, that's very weird (somebody has to fix something there), and then it's `${s?replace(r'\n', '<br>')}`.

Comment: Yes, that string contains `\n` but when I print it in logs it is not showing `\n` in console. Also tried with `${s?replace(r'\n', '<br>')}`

Comment: FreeMarker `${}` doesn't remove `\n`, or anything (unless you have some funny `#escape`).  So at this point I suspect that the `\n`-s are already missing when they reach the template. What does this show: `${s?js_string}`

Comment: as you said when I print that updated text after replacing there is no `\n` in it. It is showing as expected result in console instead of `\n`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
${myString.replace("\\\n", "\n")}
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).